# How to generate .cabal file from package.yml

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I removed package.yml file to use .cabal file instead. Now I'd like to try defining everything in package.yml, and let stack to generate .cabal file auatomatically.

But when I manually converted .cabal file to package.yml and delete .cabal file and ran `stack build`, it shows me this error:

```
Stack looks for packages in the directories configured in the 'packages' variable defined in your stack.yaml
The current entry points to /Users/leo/zhangchiqing/hello/ but no .cabal file could be found there.
```

How can I generate the .cabal file from package.yml?

Answer (score 8):

Run `hpack` in the directory containing the `package.yaml`. You can install `hpack` by running `cabal install hpack`.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I figured out. It should be `package.yaml` instead of `package.yml`